# Dropdown value onchange to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, onchange

Im trying to send a value of a dropdown on change to a php script. But with my way of solving the problem, the form and also the status String are posted twice. Once with GET parameter set, and the other without. I dont know how to solve,but maybe you are smarter than me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ennui.contentslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser()
{
var users = document.getElementById('users').value;

if (users=="" )
{
document.getElementById("pictab").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","slider.php?users="+users,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.reload();
}

<?php 
//.............
//..............
//.............
//..............
$soso = mysql_num_rows($connn3);
for($i=0;$i<$soso;$i++)
{
echo "
$(function() {
$('#one$i').ContentSlider({
width : '280px',
height : '180px',
speed : 400,
easing : 'easeOutQuad'
});
});";
}
?>

</script>
<!-- Site JavaScript -->
<form>
<select id="users" name="users" onChange="showUser()" >
<option value="bikes">Bikes</option>
<option value="zub">Stuff/option>
<option value="sonst">Other</option>

</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<?php 


if(isset($_GET['users'])){
echo "<h2>Q posted</h2>";
$q = $_GET['users'];
echo $q;
//DB QUERY WITH Q

}elseif(!isset($q)){
echo "KEIN Q GEPOSTET";
// DB QUERY WITHOUT Q
}
?>
```

Comment: WHat is `xmlhttp.reload()` supposed to do? I can't find documentation of that method.

Comment: why don't you want to use jquery?

Comment: And if you're using jQuery, why don't you use its AJAX methods instead of writing all that XMLHTTP stuff out?

Comment: Please use proper indenting to increase readability. And you should use `encodeURIComponent` to encode GET parameters. And use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS.

Answer (score 4):

You've included Jquery into your project so use its features. Mostly [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to handle Ajax requests.

```
$(function (){ //document is loaded so we can bind events

  $("#users").change(function (){ //change event for select
     $.ajax({  //ajax call
        type: "POST",      //method == POST 
        url: "slider.php", //url to be called
       data: { users:  $("#users option:selected").val()} //data to be send 
     }).done(function( msg ) { //called when request is successful msg
       //do something with msg which is response
             $("#txtHint").html(msg); //this line will put the response to item with id `#txtHint`.
     });
   });
 });
```

The php part of code should be in **slider.php**. Moreover, in example I use **POST** but if you want **GET** simply change `type: "GET"`. In script.php to get value of it use:

`$_POST['users'];` or if you change the type to GET then `$_GET['users']` you can also use `$_REQUEST['users']` which handles POST, GET, COOKIE.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `$_REQUEST` - it's not very safe to use. Use each of the separate superglobals instead

Comment: @Bojangles it's one of possiblities not recommendation :) but I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your are actually making 2 calls. One in Javascript to the PHP file and the other your echoing no matter what is set. I would comment but haven't got enough juice yet.

Try and echo out $_GET and see what your are actually setting before the call and after the call. From there you may be able to see what's actually going on. I hope this helps guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name=document.forms["myform"]["user"].value;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "yourpagenmae.php",
data: { name: user }
    ,
    success: function(msg) {
       // alert(msg);

    }
});
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score -1):

//view file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //use jquery get method
    $('#users').change(function() {
        //get the user value
        var user = $('#users').val();

        $.getJSON( "http://localhost/test.php?users="+user, function( data1 ) {

            console.log(data1);

            //status
            if (data1.status) {
                alert(data1.q);

                //whatever response variable key
                $('#txtHint').html(data1.q)
            } else {
                alert('error'+data1.q);
            }
        });
  });
});
</script>
<!-- Site JavaScript -->
<form>
    <select id="users" name="users" >
    <option value="bikes">Bikes</option>
    <option value="zub">Stuff</option>
    <option value="sonst">Other</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>

<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

//test.php file

```
<?php 

$data = array();

if(isset($_GET['users'])){
//echo "<h2>Q posted</h2>";
$q = $_GET['users'];

$data['status'] = true;
$data['q'] = $q;


}elseif(!isset($q)){

$data['status'] = false;
$data['q'] = 'KEIN Q GEPOSTET';

}

header('Content-type:application/json');
//json response
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: where is explanation? Binding events when document is not ready may lead to problems and won't always work. Onchange select is binde to function that doesn't exists. Your answer is so invalid.

Comment: check the comments before the lines. I hope you go through the entire code before pressing down vote

Comment: what comments? There is no ready event, your code won't even execute because it has errors as I wrote above. For example where this function `onChange="showUser()"` is declared? Refering to same file with ajax is not wise as well.

Comment: still code is not separated. Why to use ajax if it's all in the same file?

Comment: everything is proper what you want to separate

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your quick answer. But the script seems not to work, firebug detects an error     TypeError: jQuery.parseJSON is not a function


data1 = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: With binding jQuery 1.4.1 the first problem is solved. But now there's a problem with JSON Encode:

uncaught exception: Invalid JSON: 

Think we are close :)

Comment: use console.log(data1) and see what you are getting also add   header("Content-type:application/json"); before json_encode

Comment: Now ive splitted the php part in a seperate file. After all, the callback seems to be 0 ( same error in firebug logging data1)

Comment: now it's should work it's tested use latest jquery version  reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/